# Get field value: JSON response from feature service

Tags: javascript, json, rest, feature-service, arcgis-10.7

I have JavaScript in work order management software:

```
load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");
importPackage(java.util)
importPackage(Packages.psdi.server)
var ctx = new HashMap();
ctx.put("url","https://something.com/arcgis/rest/services/something/zones/MapServer/8/query?geometry=123456%2C1234567&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&f=pjson");
service.invokeScript("LIB_HTTPCLIENT",ctx);
var jsonResp = ctx.get("response");
service.log(jsonResp);
```

The script sends a request (with coordinates) to a feature service:

> `https://something.com/arcgis/rest/services/something/zones/MapServer/8/query?geometry=123456%2C1234567&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&f=pjson`

The feature service (REST) returns information about the feature that the coordinates/point intersected with.

```
{
 "displayFieldName": "DAY",
 "fieldAliases": {
  "OBJECTID": "OBJECTID",
  "DAY": "DAY",
  "ZONE": "Area",
  "SHAPE.AREA": "SHAPE.AREA",
  "SHAPE.LEN": "SHAPE.LEN"
 },
 "fields": [
  {
   "name": "OBJECTID",
   "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
   "alias": "OBJECTID"
  },
  {
   "name": "DAY",
   "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
   "alias": "DAY",
   "length": 10
  },
  {
   "name": "ZONE",
   "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
   "alias": "Area",
   "length": 6
  },
  {
   "name": "SHAPE.AREA",
   "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
   "alias": "SHAPE.AREA"
  },
  {
   "name": "SHAPE.LEN",
   "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
   "alias": "SHAPE.LEN"
  }
 ],
 "features": [
  {
   "attributes": {
    "OBJECTID": 327,
    "DAY": "Tuesday",
    "ZONE": "1",                     <-------zone is here
    "SHAPE.AREA": 5154109.08323004,
    "SHAPE.LEN": 10563.5744286387
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

**I want to isolate the zone number from the JSON text** so that I can insert it into a record/field.

How can I parse/isolate the zone number using JavaScript?

Comment: features is an array with one element (note the square bracket). You're very close -try changing `service.log(obj.features.attributes.zone)` to `service.log(obj.features[0].attributes.zone)`

Comment: @StevenKay : A related question here:       https://stackoverflow.com/q/57617494/10936066

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can parse the JSON text using `JSON.parse`.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonResp);
service.log(obj.features[0].attributes.ZONE)
```

Notes:

1. The JSON `features` element is an **array with a single element in it** (note the square brackets).

   - Put an index reference after features: `features[0]`. *Credit goes to @Steven Kay.*
2. The field name is **case sensitive**.

   - `zone` didn't work, but `ZONE` did.

*That was harder than it needed to be!*